# How to prove "if $2^x=2^y$ so $x=y$"

Tags: logarithms, exponentiation

I got this to prove and I don't know how.
I tried everything but I just don't know how to prove it. thanks for helping.

Comment: You need the fact that $2^x$ is injective across its entire domain.

Comment: I’m confused...if you tried everything, wouldn’t you have found the solution?

Comment: Showing that $f(x) = f(y) \implies x = y$ is the definition of a function being one-to-one (injective).

Comment: Try showing for $a\in\mathbb{R}^+$, $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=a^x$ is one-one. Your question is a particualr case for $a=2$.

Comment: @Yadati: you need $a\in\Bbb R^+$.

Comment: @Clayton: Ah..Yes, I shall correct it.

Comment: Where did you come across this problem? What do you know about exponentials? Is this for a university course? School work? I've voted to close this due to a lack of context, as this question is really difficult to answer without knowing the answers to these questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=2^x$ is injective (for instance because it is monotone increasing). Since $2^x=2^y$ means $f(x)=f(y)$, this implies $x=y$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the logarithm on both sides, we get$$x\ln(2)=y\ln(2)$$

Comment: You technically answer the question with the question. The very existence of $\ln$ (in fact you should apply $\log_2$ instead) requires that $x\mapsto e^x$ (or $x\mapsto 2^x$) is invertible (in particular 1:1).

Comment: @Yanko Well, it depends heavily on how you define logs too. They are not always defined as the inverse of exponentiation.